# How does the analyse paramethers for SonarQube scanner for jenkins with maven works?

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Hi I'm trying to analyse java maven project with sonarQube scanner for Jenkins, using method described in here: [SonarQube Scanner Documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins), now in the section **Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner for Maven**, there it says that into created Jenkins maven job you just need to add into goals: $SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL

It looked like this: [Build Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVwKq.png)

Now I did this, you can also find more of those environmental variables after clicking on the blue question mark right next to prepare sonarQube scanner environment in the build environment section.

It worked and has analyzed one gitlab repository which I have specified within Source Code Management in the [Source Code Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo5og.png).

When I, however, tried to change this to another repository, firstly It just analyzed the same repository I had specified before and it ran an analysis on the old one and also sent results from the old one to my SonarQube server, it completely ignored that I specified different gitlab repository in the Source code management part.

Later on, I tried to add clean install option to maven goals,  it has thrown an error at the end of the build output console:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project Export: Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

So this brings me to a part where I think I'm doing something wrong about the configuration of environmental variables, I don't understand what are the actual values of $SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL or any other environmental variables.

My final goal is to be able to analyze Gitlab repositories with java maven projects, from Jenkins.

Comment: You link to screenshots from the first iteration of your configuration. It would be more helpful to know your current configuration.

Comment: My current iteration looks the same as the one I have posted. Also how do you mean build step for building my code is missing ?

Comment: To be more specific, I have kept the same job config as the one in the screenshot, I have only tried to analyze different repo when the error I'm writing about showed up in console output.

Comment: @dur I'm using maven project job, but I was doing it the same way as it's specified in the documentation written in the link above. All the project I'm going to analyze from the gitlab repos are maven projects. When I use the sonar scanner in post build step I need to specify the location of files to analyze within the gitlab repo. In documentation about analysing maven projects, It says you just check the prepare sonarqube scanner environment and then just to add 
$SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL to the goals as I have posted in the image in my previous post...

Comment: @dur So i have eventually figured it out, but your answer that the documentation is for freestyle project was really heplfull, could you please post it as an answer so I can accept it ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger SonarQube analysis **after building your project** with a *standard Jenkins Build Step*, see [Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins):

> **Features**
>
> This plugin lets you centralize the configuration of SonarQube server connection details in Jenkins global configuration.
>
> Then you can trigger SonarQube analysis from Jenkins using standard Jenkins Build Steps to trigger analysis with:
>
> - SonarQube Scanner
> - SonarQube Scanner for Maven
> - SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild

or with a Post-build Action, see [Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner for Maven](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven):

> The *Post-build Action* for Maven analysis is still available, but is deprecated.

Using a *Freestyle project* you could add a build step for SonarQube analysis like:

[image]

Using a *Maven project* ([Maven Integration](https://plugins.jenkins.io/maven-plugin)) you could add a Post-build Action for SonarQube analysis like:

[image]

Comment: Alright, It finally works, I have eventually just added the jdk to a jenkins, I would need to instal sonar on that slave too...